# List folders which has not a custom property in Google Drive API v3 and .NET

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I want to list all those items that has no `imdb` property key or if its value is null/empty.
I tried wtih (I'm using Google Drive API for .NET) :

```
var request = PrepareListRequest(itemsPerPage, nextPageToken);
request.Q = $"'{id}' in parents and not properties has (imdb) or properties(imdb) is null"; // don't know here.
```

And the method:

```
private FilesResource.ListRequest PrepareListRequest(int itemsPerPage, string nextPageToken)
{
  var request = dataService.Files.List();
  request.PageSize = itemsPerPage;
  request.SupportsAllDrives = true;
  request.IncludeItemsFromAllDrives = true;

  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nextPageToken))
  {
    request.PageToken = nextPageToken;
  }

  request.Fields = "nextPageToken, files";
  return request;
}
```

But I got 400 error:

[image]

Update 1: I tried also

```
  request.Q = $"'{id}' in parents and not properties has {{ key='imdb' }}";
```

Got same error.

Update 2: I tried:

```
 request.Q = $"'{id}' in parents (and properties has {{ key='imdb' and value=null) }} or not properties has {{ key='imdb' and value='' }})";
```

I want to get files/folders which don't have `imdb` in properties list.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: Your request is wrong.  Could be for a number of reasons.  Looks like you are getting an http error 400.  It could be a TLS issue but first check the format of your request at following : https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference

Comment: @jdweng I don't have problem if I use list without using `Q` property. I don't know good format for `properties` because documentation is not good enough. The 400 error has nothing to do with TLS

Comment: You never said that it was working with other commands.  I said "Could" meaning I wasn't sure.  The link says format of request is : "list GET  /files/fileId/comments/commentId/replies"

Comment: @jdweng I'm nothing to do with comment. I work with files only.

Comment: See following for more details : https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource

Comment: Did you read my question/post ? I know that reference and is not helping me.

Comment: A query has a question mark with parameters.  All the google API are similar.  So you can use a URL with a question mark as shown on following page : https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest

Comment: In the current stage, when you use `properties` of the search query, it is required to use both key and value. It seems that this is the current specification. I think that the reason of your error is due to this. So in your case, how about this search query? `'###' in parents and properties has {key='imdb' and value=''}`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref) But if I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, seems to work with both combination. But I want to get those which don't have `imdb` properties key. I don't know how and I'm stuck here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, if want to display items which don't have `xxx` in properties:

```
request.Q = $"'{id}' in parents and (properties has {{ key='xxx' and value='' }} or not properties has {{ key='xxx' and value='' }})";
```