# List items based on a property key in Google Drive API v3 and .NET

Tags: google-drive-api

I succeeded to manage my issue: [List folders which has not a custom property in Google Drive API v3 and .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63559883/list-folders-which-has-not-a-custom-property-in-google-drive-api-v3-and-net)

Now, I have other challenge.

I have custom property called `imdb` and it has any value (not empty).

I tried to figure out how to retrieve those items which have `imdb` property in list (no matter what `value` have). I don't want getting entire full list and check one by one the `Properties` dictionary (I have 300-320 items and is growing).

```
request.Q = $"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and properties has {{ key='imdb' and value='/*WHAT SHOULD DO ?*/' }}";
```

Seems that query works only if provide both components `key` and `value`, otherwise I will get 400 as well

I tried also:

```
request.Q = $"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and properties has {{ key='imdb' and value!='' }}";
```

but it gave me 400 (bad request), seems `value!=''` is not valid

The `request` object is:

```
var request = dataService.Files.List();
```

and

```
...
dataService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
  {
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "XXXX"
});
```

Any advice ?

Answer (score 2):

### As for now, it is not possible to query for properties without specifying the exact value

This issue is being [investigated](https://issuetracker.google.com/160827659) by Google.
As a consequence, you can not use the `not`, `contains` or other operators that would be helpful for your query.
All you can do (not particularly efficient) is to

- list all of you files specifying `fields` to `files/properties`
- filter the list manually for the results where `files/properties` is not empty
- compare the filtered list against the results of
  `request.Q = $"'{id}' in parents and (properties has {{ key='xxx' and value='' }} or not properties has {{ key='xxx' and value='' }})";`

I would recommend you to comment on the existing issue to remind Google that it still has not been implemented.